# extract words where vowel sign is used consecutively

Tags: python

I am trying to extract words where vowel sign is used consecutively twice (or more than 2 times) next to each other.

```
texts = ['ane', 'mood', 'xao', 'pqr', 'aa']
signs = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

for i in texts:
    for x in i:
        if x in signs:
            print ("double vowel sign exists in", i)
```

This will print:

```
double vowel sign exists in ane
double vowel sign exists in ane
double vowel sign exists in mood
double vowel sign exists in mood
double vowel sign exists in xao
double vowel sign exists in xao
double vowel sign exists in aa
double vowel sign exists in aa
```

The expected output is:

```
double vowel sign exists in mood
double vowel sign exists in mood
double vowel sign exists in xao
double vowel sign exists in xao
double vowel sign exists in aa
double vowel sign exists in aa
```

(better if not repeated)

Comment: If the current character is a vowel, you need to check the previous character, and break out if the inner loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this,

```
texts = ['ane', 'mood', 'xao', 'pqr', 'aa']
signs = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

for i in texts:
    for x in zip(i, i[1:]):
        if all(check in signs for check in x):
            print(f"double vowel sign exists in {i}")
```

Output:

```
double vowel sign exists in mood
double vowel sign exists in xao
double vowel sign exists in aa
```

Comment: Upvoted. This is good Pythonic code, except I don’t know if there’s a need to continue looking if a pair of vowels is found. Based on OP’s expected output, that seems to be the case, although how come there are two pairs in `mood` is beyond me.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most concise but quite readable.
Stops iterate a word as soon as a double-vowel has been found.

```py
texts = ["ane", "mood", "xao", "pqr", "aa"]
signs = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]


def has_two_consecutive_vowels(word: str) -> bool:
    counter = 0
    for letter in word:
        counter = counter + 1 if letter in signs else 0
        if counter > 1:
            return True
    return False


for word in texts:
    if has_two_consecutive_vowels(word):
        print(f"double vowel sign exists in {word}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below solution. We loop over each string in `texts` and split each string to a list of characters like `['a', 'n', 'e']` for `"ane"`. Then you can loop over this list and check if the character at each index and at the next index is also a vowel. We append such strings into an empty list and can print them.

```
texts = ['ane', 'mood', 'xao', 'pqr', 'aa']
signs = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
consecutive_vowels = []

for i in texts:
    list_i = list(i)
    for j in range(len(list_i)-1):
        if (list_i[j] in signs) and (list_i[j + 1] in signs):
            consecutive_vowels.append(i)
            
for word in consecutive_vowels:
    print("double vowel sign exists in {}".format(word))
```

Output:

```
double vowel sign exists in mood
double vowel sign exists in xao
double vowel sign exists in aa
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex version. It just checks for double vowels, and keeps the word if it finds them.

```
dbl = __import__('re').compile(r'[aeiou]{2}')
txt = ('ane', 'mood', 'xao', 'pqr', 'aa')
mtc = [w for w in txt if dbl.search(w)]
print('double vowels in:', *mtc, sep='\n\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to define a required pattern.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

```
import re             
pattern = ".*[" + ''.join(signs) + "]{2,}"
for _text in texts:
    if re.search(pattern, _text):
        print(f"double vowel sign exists in {_text}")
        
double vowel sign exists in mood
double vowel sign exists in xao
double vowel sign exists in aa
```

Comment: "ane" should not be selected because there is "n" between "ae".